# what is the difference between config and release tags while generating signed apk?

Tags: java, android

I saw some tutorials of how to make release apk and after I had finished I realized some lines was added to gradle ,something like that

```
signingConfigs {
    config {
        keyAlias 'akeyalias'
        keyPassword '*******'
        storeFile file("apath")
        storePassword '********'
    }
  }
```

but while I was searching on the internet or some questions I see that

```
 signingConfigs {
    release {
       keyAlias 'akeyalias'
        keyPassword '*******'
        storeFile file("apath")
        storePassword '********'
    }
  }
```

so what is the difference and is it ok to use config to generate release apk?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an application which is being developed by a several developers you will probably want to remove the signing key from your build.gradle file and put it into a separate properties file--for example for safe keeping you would create a separate properties file and add the signing keys like this:

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    ...
  }
```

Directly from Android Docs:

> When you create a signing configuration, Android Studio adds your
>   signing information in plain text to the module's build.gradle files.
>   If you are working with a team or open-sourcing your code, you should
>   move this sensitive information out of the build files so it is not
>   easily accessible to others. To do this, you should create a separate
>   properties file to store secure information and refer to that file in
>   your build files...

There is much more to actually moving the signing configuration to a separate file so see this section [Remove signing information from your build files](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#secure-shared-keystore)

If you are solely in control of your application or you trust your team (not advisable) you can leave the signing key in the build.gradle and use the other form like:

```
signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("my-release-key.jks")
            storePassword "password"
            keyAlias "my-alias"
            keyPassword "password"
        }
    }
```

Comment: good explanation I am recently reading about how to hide sensitive info in operate file instate of gradle but I am currently asking about release and config keywords like in the example is there big different between them?